# How/where is the global variable $wp_registered_widgets filled?

Tags: widgets, globals

I have a problem of widgets not showing up, trying to investigate why $wp_registered_widgets is empty.

Can somebody tell me where it gets filled from the database? How can I find out why the default widgets are not set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/nav.html?_variables/wp_registered_widgets.html), `$wp_registered_widgets` is defined in wp-includes/widgets.php (as expected). You should be able to debug it by doing something like this:

```
function yoast_print_active_widgets() {
    global $wp_registered_widgets;    
    echo '<pre>'.print_r( $wp_registered_widgets, 1 ).'</pre>';
}
add_action('init','yoast_print_active_widgets');
```

Then you could loop through the different stages, from `init`, to `send_headers` to `wp_head` and see where stuff goes wrong...

Comment: The link is now broken, so I can't see what part of the code you're trying to highlight. Another good reminder why it's better to include as much info as possible in the answer. I've looked through widgets.php and can't find where this dang variable is filled!

Comment: @jerclarke, the definition can be found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.1/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L26) (and initialized at line 34).  The global is then populated by way of the function `wp_register_sidebar_widget()` starting on [line 386](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.1/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L353).